# Is this cairn/mound-like structure in Germany real or imagined?

Tags: ancient-history, europe, prehistory

EDIT: I have found the answer - it was Waldviertel Pyramid. I have provided details in the answer.

The thing is that I have either read about or seen on a TV documentary about a certain cairn-like structure and I can't find it with my google searches. Although I am 100% (or, let's make it 99%) sure that it was a real thing, I am really starting to feel like I have misremembered something and that there is no such thing.

What I remember:

- location: most likely Germany, but also possibly Austria or Switzerland (this is the thing that I doubt the most about my memory)
- if not Germany, it IS certainly located in a country that is NOT famous for cairns
- shape: circular
- general look: built out of smaller stones; I THINK it is a bit overgrown by vegetation (grass) on the top
- it looks similar to [this](https://www.france-voyage.com/visuals/photos/grabhugel-bougon-23872_w1000.webp) , but only has one level (no "steps")
- it was built in a forest region, not in a meadow
- I saw it only on photos, but my guess would be in the range between 5-10 meters in diameter
- it is a "real thing", not a modern structure that looks like ancient cairn. As someone who lives in a region covered by rocks, it is not unusual to see large piles of rock or relatively modern origin (I had one myself  near my country house until 15 years ago).
- the weird thing about it (and the thing responsible for me memorizing it) was that it is isolated and its origins unclear (there is no clear evidence of cairn-building prehistoric culture in that area apart from that cairn/mound)

Comment: Might be worth reviewing meta to understand what we're looking for in a [good question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3886/1401)

Comment: I find some hits concerning cairns in the Maulbronn Germany area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, this turned out to be a quite extreme case of misremembering.
The building was in fact [Waldviertel Pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldviertel_Pyramid).

What I got right:

- it was built in a forest in Austria (I know, not Germany, but a German-speaking country)
- it has rock "walls" covered with grass on top
- there is no sign of prehistoric activity in the area
- its origins are unknown
- the largest diameter is 14 meters, meaning the rest of them are in the 5-10 meter range I have estimated

What I got wrong:

- it HAS "steps" - it looks more like a pyramid (hence the name) than I have (mis)remembered (it has, or had, one side damaged, so it might have influenced my false memory)
- it is likely only several hundred, not several thousand, years old

The explanation for the last one is also how I found it - I have searched through all .pdf files on ancient sites on my old computer and found it is a pseudoarcheological book, in which it IS claimed to be "of ancient origin".

Last, but not the least. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, you should click the checkmark next to it in order to "accept" it.

Comment: I tried, but it said: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"

Comment: Ah, that makes sense (and it also makes sense that I wouldn't know that). OK then.

Comment: hahah, yeah, I don't think it is very common to answer your own questions, but so it happened :)